# Вывод ПК из сна средствами Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Есть ли возможность выводить ПК под Win8.1 из сна средствами Python3?

Comment: Можно: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае помогло запуск скрипта через планировщик задач, и из сна вытаскивает и запускает, что мне нужно

Comment: Когда спит его ведь только кнопка включения пробуждает?